# UINavigationController deinit never called

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, stack, deinit

From some `ViewController` of my `UINavigationController` stack I present another `ViewController` and will never come back, but the problem is that `deinit{}` is not called. How should I remove each `ViewController` from the stack before navigation? Or should I use some other method? Now my code looks like

```
let destinationVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("revealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
self.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you call `presentViewController:animated:completion:` you will present the new `viewController` **modally**, outside of the `navigationController's` hierarchy.

If you wish to present it within the `navigationController` hierarchy use:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

And if you want to *change* the view hierarchy, the `navigationController` has a property `viewControllers` which can be set with or without *animation*.

```
self.navigationController!.setViewControllers([destinationVC],
           animated: true)
```

See the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) for more information.

Comment: It helped to deinit, but problem is that I want my destination ViewController not to be embedded in NavigationController (to be outside of its hierarchy): I have intro VCs, that won't be shown ever again until user quits app.

Comment: I see! =) Sounds like you have two different _view suites_ then. What I would do is to either just set the `rootViewController` property of your applications `UIWindow` to the desired `viewController`, or preferably having a _baseViewController_ that can perform the switch between the different *suites*.

Comment: I've fixed my problem by adding `self.navigationController!.setViewControllers([], animated: false)` to `viewDidDisappear` method. Not sure if it is right approach but at least it works.